# Question about terraform.tfstate mappings

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

This document suggests that the `backend.key` setting will be automatically mapped to `ARM_ACCESS_KEY` environment variable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage

[image]

Based on what rule or mechanics `backend.key` reads `ARM_ACCESS_KET` environment variable? where is it documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up blob storage keys and access keys. A "key" in this sense represents a file path in blob storage, while an "access_key" is a login to that blob.

If you fill an environment variable named `ARM_ACCESS_KEY` with the given storage account access key described in that documentation, then you don't have to define that access key as a constant in the backend configuration (which would be insecure).

The settings you have thus far are correct. If you define the environment variable I described above, Terraform will use it when connecting to remote state storage.

Comment: Ok, so ARM_ACCESS_KEY  is a predefined name.

Comment: Yes, it will be consumed by the azure CLI/SDK/API when attempting to authenticate access, which is what Terraform calls when configuring the state backend.